# How to resolve this error in Xcode? "Error while fetching remote repository/The source control operation was cancelled"

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I have an Xcode project using Swift Packages. When I try to build my app, I get this error:

> Error while fetching remote repository
> The source control operation was cancelled

I tried cleaning and building again, it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Right click on "Package Dependencies" in the project navigator:

[image: screenshot of Package Dependencies]

- Click on Resolve Package Versions:

[image: screenshot of Resolve Package Versions]

Comment: If only it was this simple and reliable...